# Add html5 attributes to form inputs using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@Html.TextBox("UserName", null, new { /* ... */ })
```

How would i add properties like `data-foo="bar"` and `required` to the htmlattributes object?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using MVC3 you can use underscores in your html attributes, they are converted to dashes

```
@Html.TextBox("UserName", null, new { data_foo = "bar", required = "" })
```

html result

```
<input data-foo="bar" id="UserName" name="UserName" required="" type="text" value="">
```

Second option. Use dictionary instead of anonymous object

```
@Html.TextBox("UserName", null, new Dictionary<string, object> { {"data-foo", "bar"}, {"required", ""} })
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a key without a value in the object? Since the `required` markup is `required` and not `required=""`?

Comment: But `required=""` is also proper syntax. Look [HTML5 required Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_required.asp)